# Why will Gson pretty-print to the console, but not the file?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a class, let's call it Cls, with some values in it. When I use a Gson instance declared with `GsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting().create()` and use that to serialize a Cls object and print the resulting JSON string to console, I get it nicely formatted, like so:

```
{
    "foo":"bar",
    "foo2":["b1","b2"],
    "foo3":12
}
```

This is all well and good, but when I then create a JsonWriter (from a FileWriter with an absolute path) and use the Gson instance's `toJson(Object, Class, JsonWriter)` method with Cls, the resulting file does NOT get formatted nicely. It instead looks like this:

```
{"foo":"bar","foo2":["b1","b2"],"foo3":12}
```

This defeats the whole point of pretty printing. Why is it doing this, and how can I make it stop?

Comment: Open the file with Notepad++. If you are using the regular Notepad, it may not display correctly.

Comment: Also, I never use the writer. I first save the pretty-print to string and use `Files.write(path, prettyPrintString.getBytes());`

Comment: @Sedrick I am using Notepad++. It still does it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably, you're using something like this

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

try (FileWriter fileWriter = ...) {
    gson.toJson(new Example(), Example.class, new JsonWriter(fileWriter));
}
```

The `JsonWriter` wasn't created from the `Gson` object and is therefore not configured to pretty print. You can, instead, retrieve a `JsonWriter` instance from the `Gson` object with [`newJsonWriter`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#newJsonWriter-java.io.Writer-)

```
gson.toJson(new Example(), Example.class, gson.newJsonWriter(fileWriter));
```

which

> Returns a new JSON writer configured for the settings on this Gson instance.

This instance will pretty-print.

You can also set the `indent` on your own instance

```
JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(fileWriter);
jsonWriter.setIndent("  ");
gson.toJson(new Example(), Example.class, jsonWriter);
```